# Network interface issue after upgrading CentOS 6 to 7

Tags: linux, centos, troubleshooting

Recently I have upgraded my VM Server from CentOS 6 to 7. The upgrade completed without any error but the network interface is not showing in `ifconfig` and there is no file called `ifcfg-eth0`.

Before upgrade there were two interfaces `eth0` and `eth1`, now there is nothing except `lo`.

In `system-config-network` under device configuration I don't find any interface.

`ip addr show` gives me three interfaces

`lo` `enp0s3` and `enp0s8` there is no IPADDR assign to this interface.

How can I assign it manually?

[image]

[image]

**Solution**

Its working with this `dhclient enp0s3`

Comment: `ifconfig` is a depricated command and you should avoid using it. Use `ip` command instead. Also see if `NetworkManager` is running.  Your interfaces might be renamed like  `enoXX` where `XX` is the number of the PCIe slot on your machine/server.

Comment: I have edited the question, I am able to run the command `ip addr show` but unable to `locate enp0` file on the system. is there any other way to create a new interface on `CentOS 7`

Comment: Can you run `dmesg | grep -i 'enp0s[38]'`  Also can you do a listing of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`

Comment: There is no output from `dmesg | grep -i 'enp0s[38]'`. I have edited the question

Comment: It seems that the kernel module / driver for your network card(s) is not loaded or available.  Can you show the output of `lspci |grep -i ether`.  Please provide more details like `nmcli connection show`  as well.

Comment: The output of `vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` ?

Comment: I have added both the output requested. `nmcli` command not found , there is no such command starting from `nm`.

Comment: Try to found `HWADDR` and add it to `ifcfg-eth0` something like `HWADDR=08:00:27:08:47:E9` and restart network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CentOS 7, network settings are managed by NetworkManager. So, use [nmtui](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Networking_Config_Using_nmtui.html) or [nmcli](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Network_Config_Using_nmcli.html) to assign IP addresses. Make sure the packages `NetworkManager` and `NetworkManager-tui` are installed.

Or, if you want to revert the management method to `ifcfg-*` files, follow CentOS FAQ sections [#2](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS7#head-62d45421abea0220e3038796e3dd5315906fa493), [#3](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS7#head-31ebc6642958a0df12304d6aab9a49034a3b7802) and [#4](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS7#head-a21a9e454157700367c9b7e9ccb1ff9954bec881).

Comment: As the interface is not there I am unable to download/install the `NetworkManager` package. Do you think the provided link can help me use `ifcfg-eth0`. I'm stuck at #3

Comment: @AvinashRedy kernel arguments are set in `/etc/default/grub` file if grub2 is properly installed. Follow [these instructions](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Grub2). Or, if the system still uses grub-legacy, modify kernel arguments in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.

Comment: @AvinashRedy, network interfaces seem to exist in your system. You can assign temporary addresses by running command lines like `ip addr add dev enp0s3 192.168.33.33/24` and `ip route add default via 192.168.33.1`. Or, if your network has a DHCP server, `dhclient enp0s3` or `dhcpcd enp0s3`.

Comment: Its working now thx Anderson.